# regex preg_match|preg_match_all in php

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to come up with a regex that constructs an array that looks like the one below, from the following string

```
$str = 'Hello world [something here]{optional}{optional}{optional}{n possibilities of this}';
```

So far I have `/^(\*{0,3})(.+)\[(.*)\]((?:{[a-z ]+})?)$/`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello world [something here]{optional}{optional}{optional}{n possibilities of this}
            [1] => 
            [2] => Hello world
            [3] => something here
            [4] => {optional}
            [5] => {optional}
            [6] => {optional}
            [7] => ...
            [8] => ...
            [9] => {n of this}
        )
)
```

What would be a good approach for this? Thanks

Comment: How important is it to get the resulting array precisely like in the question? Also, is that a "real" string that you want to match against or a simplified example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need two steps for this.

1. `(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)` will get you `Hello world`, `something here`, and `{optional}...{optional}`.
2. Applying `\{(.+?)\}` to the last element from the previous step will get you optional params.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which I believe is even cleaner than you have asked for:

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/lKTDv)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXazfM/1))

```
$str = 'Hello world [something here]{optional}{optional}{optional}{n possibilities of this}';

var_export(preg_split('/ *\[|\]|(?=\{)/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Hello world',
  1 => 'something here',
  2 => '{optional}',
  3 => '{optional}',
  4 => '{optional}',
  5 => '{n possibilities of this}',
)
```

`preg_split()` will be breaking your string on three possible occurrences (removing these occurrences in the process):

- `*\[` means zero or more spaces followed by a opening square bracket.
- `\]` means a closing square bracket.
- `?=\{)` means a zero-length character (the position just before...) an opening curly bracket.

*My pattern generates an empty element between `]` and `{`.  To eliminate this useless element, I added the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to the function call.